# Azure ACL virtual machines on load balanced set

Tags: azure, load-balancing, acl, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to restrict access to my 2 Ubuntu VMs that I have created in Azure for the default elasticsearch port of 9200 and can't seem to get it working.

My virtual machines are part of the same cloud service and the endpoints are setup to use the same load-balanced set so that any request to the cloud service on port 9200 will be load balanced between my 2 VMs.  That is all working as expected it seems.

I want to set these up so only my Azure Websites can access them directly so I need to manage the ACL for the VMs I figured.  To test it out I tried setting the ACL to deny my specific IP address for the port 9200 endpoint on both servers, but when I do that I can still access them over that port it seems.

I tested denying my IP address to the SSH endpoint and I was successfully blocked from getting onto the servers over SSH.  So my only guess is that the load balancing set for these endpoints is causing the ACL to not work properly.

Is there a better way to handle this, maybe using Traffic Manager instead of the load balanced set for the VMs on the same cloud service?  I think my backup plan would be to use iptables on each VM to set the restrictions but ideally I'd be able to handle this in the Azure portal if possible.

Thanks.